# Rajawali Carboard OBJ File

Tags: android, google-cardboard, rajawali

I just started using Rajawali and the Cardboard SDK (the integration that you can find in Rajawali’s repository). Based on the examples provided (loaders) in the repository and following the instructions to set up a new project I have created an example where I create a sphere (and attach a texture to it) and load an OBJ file, the odd thing is that I can actually see the sphere and the texture but not the OBJ object. I created a similar example where the difference just resides on the class that I’m extending, in one example I extend the RajawaliRender class (in this one I see the OBJ file) and in the other I extend the RajawaliCarboardRender. I would really appreciate if you can give a hand or provide me an example because I’m stuck and I have tried everything I can think of.

This is the content of my initScene method in both examples:

```
public void initScene(){

    directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(1f, .2f, -1.0f);
    directionalLight.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    directionalLight.setPower(2);
    getCurrentScene().addLight(directionalLight);
    Material material = new Material();
    material.enableLighting(true);
    material.setDiffuseMethod(new DiffuseMethod.Lambert());
    material.setColor(0);

    Texture earthTexture = new Texture("Earth", R.drawable.earthtruecolor_nasa_big);
    try{
        material.addTexture(earthTexture);

    } catch (ATexture.TextureException error){
        Log.d("DEBUG", "TEXTURE ERROR");
    }

    earthSphere = new Sphere(1, 24, 24);
    earthSphere.setMaterial(material);
    getCurrentScene().addChild(earthSphere);
    getCurrentCamera().setZ(14.2f);

    final LoaderOBJ loaderOBJ = new LoaderOBJ(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager, R.raw.multiobjects_obj);
    loadModel(loaderOBJ, this, R.raw.multiobjects_obj);

}
```

Comment: Hi @Leonardo Naranjo,  I have the same problem, and did you solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I stucked on this place too... Perhaps are you have a solution...?